# Rails 4 pass data from controller to model attr_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok, I'm quite confused and a little stuck here, I'm trying to pass data to my Model via attr_accessor but I cant find the right way. Here is my setup so far:

```ruby
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :current_league

  protected

  def current_league
    @current_league ||= Conf.all.order('updated_at ASC').last.league
  end
end

class HerosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @heros = Hero.all.order(:name)
  end
end

class Hero < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :current_league

  def some_method
    puts current_league
  end
end

<% @heros.each do |hero| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= hero.some_method %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Now how do I set the `@current_league` inside my model? I know I can have an `attr_accessor` inside my model, but this only applies to an instance of this model but the index action doesn't create an instance as far as I know. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have write that mathod in app controller under private area so as i know it will be usable in only all the controller because all the controller inherits from app controller so using this method in model is wring.

Comment: Check my edit, as you can see, when listing all the Heroes I want it to display the `some_method` inside the index view.

Comment: its not recommended to call controller helpers from your models

Comment: I don't want to call the helper, I want to have `@current_league` available inside my model, don't be confused by the same naming inside my model and controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@heros` variable is a collection of Hero instances. You can loop through them and set it if you want.

```
class HerosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @heros = Hero.all.order(:name).each do |hero|
      hero.current_league = current_league
    end
  end
end
```

While it works, I don't find this answer to be all that elegant. Granted, I don't know the full extend of the thing you are making, but based on the code here I would create a composite object. Something like this:

```
class HeroInLeague

  attr_reader :league, :hero

  def initialize(league, hero)
    @league = league
    @hero = hero
  end

  def some_method
    # ...
  end

end
```

Then you can create these objects inside your controller:

```
class HerosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @heros_in_league = Hero.all.order(:name).map { |hero|
      HeroInLeague.new(current_league, hero)
    }
  end
end
```

Now you've created a place for methods to go that are related the combination of heros and leagues. Why is this important? Well, with the previous approach you'd probably end up with methods on Hero that don't make any sense when there is no current league. (like the `some_method` method). That makes the Hero class a bit of a mess. Now you've created a place to put `some_method` and all its friends.

You can use [delegators](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/forwardable/Forwardable) to make the interface of `HeroInLeague` a bit more friendly, so you don't have to do `hero_in_league.hero.foo`, but can call `hero_in_league.foo` directly.

Comment: First answer looks promising, but I just tested it and it looks like it won't set the `current_league` because if I do `puts current_league ` inside the each do |hero| it wont output anything, if I put it outside the each loop it outputs the `current_league`

Comment: That's because `puts` will send the thing to STDOUT. When you are doing IRB you need to use return values. The return value of `puts` is always `nil`.

Comment: I'm not in IRB, I have now
@heros = Hero.all.order(:name) do |hero|
  hero.current_league = current_league
end
and inside my model inside the some_method I have the puts current_league but it doesnt output anything in my server

Comment: Sorry, I meant ERB, not IRB. What I meant was: `<%= @hero.some_method %>` will evaluate to `<%= puts @hero.current_league %>`, which in turn reads `<%= nil %>` which makes it output nothing. Also, you are forgetting the `each` in that code, so the block never gets called, thus never setting the current league.

Comment: Ahhhh, the each did the trick :D thanks, sometimes the small things make the difference, and now it is working like I expect it to work :)